# asp.net VB asp:DropDownList only returns default value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My DropDownList is only returning the default selected option. FYI not using code behind. The list populates from the database, but when you select any options it always returns 'NONE' which is the first option value. If I remove the selected 'NONE' Item from the list, then it returns no value at all.

The code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="sublist" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="None" Value="NONE" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Populating the list:

```
Sub GenCatList()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
        RS2 = SQL2.ExecuteReader()
        sublist.DataSource = RS2
        sublist.DataTextField = "CategoryTitle"
        sublist.DataValueField = "CategoryTitle"
        sublist.DataBind()
        RS2.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Form submission:

```
Protected Sub AddCategory_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim subcat As String = sublist.SelectedValue
    Response.Write(subcat)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Comment: Check for `IsPostBack` when binding the data.

Comment: Thanks VCWWD, I tried that and it made no difference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly, all I had to do to solve this issue was add:

Imports System.Configuration

*grumbles at ones own stupidity*

Answer (score 0):

I generally add the default option as part of the bind. As you have declared `seleted='True'` in the tag, that will alway be the case. I do the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="sublist" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
Sub GenCatList()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
        RS2 = SQL2.ExecuteReader()
        sublist.DataSource = RS2
        sublist.DataTextField = "CategoryTitle"
        sublist.DataValueField = "CategoryTitle"
        sublist.DataBind()
        RS2.Close()

        //Add default option
        sublist.Items.Insert(new ListItem("None", "NONE").Selected = true)
    End If
End Sub
```

Your other option is to try:

```
<!-- Note: the Selected attribute has been removed -->
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="sublist" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="true">
    <asp:ListItem  Text="None" Value="NONE" />
</asp:DropDownList>

SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
Sub GenCatList()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
        RS2 = SQL2.ExecuteReader()
        sublist.DataSource = RS2
        sublist.DataTextField = "CategoryTitle"
        sublist.DataValueField = "CategoryTitle"
        sublist.DataBind()
        RS2.Close()

        //Set First item as selected
        sublist.Items(0).Selected = true
    End If
End Sub
```

Note I'm a C# guy so you might need to tidy the syntax in either option

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this returns no value

Comment: Sounds like  you have something else going on with `onPageLoad`

Answer (score 0):

If you use ExecuteReader(), you have to read each record again and add to your dropdownlist. Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="sublist" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="true">
</asp:DropDownList>

SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
Sub GenCatList()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        SQL2.CommandText = "select * from Categories where SubCategory is NUll order by CategoryTitle ASC"
        RS2 = SQL2.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
        sublist.Items.Add(New ListItem(RS2.GetValue("CategoryTitle"), RS2.GetValue("CategoryTitle")))
        End While

        RS2.Close()

        //Add default option
        sublist.Items.Insert(new ListItem("None", "NONE").Selected = true)
    End If
End Sub
```

## Update after @Jadeh's comment.

Hi @Jadeh, Have you every tried direct binding method? Hope it.
Could you remove pre inserted list item none (below one) and insert it at zero index after bind? As "None" is inserted at 0, it will be set default selected.

```
//Remove below pre-inserted line
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="None" Value="NONE" />

//You may want to clear to make sure it's empty before bind.
sublist.Items.Clear()

//Bind data to sublist
con.Open()
sublist.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
sublist.DataTextField = "CategoryTitle"
sublist.DataValueField = "CategoryTitle"
sublist.DataBind()
con.Close()

//Insert at 0 index after bind.
sublist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("None", "NONE"))
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this returns no value

Comment: Hi Jadeh, Do you ever try direct binding method.

                con.Open()
                sublist.DataSource = SQL2.ExecuteReader()
                sublist.DataTextField = "CategoryTitle"
                sublist.DataValueField = "CategoryTitle"
                sublist.DataBind()
                con.Close()

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. It seems, to me, the problem is something to do with reading the data from the items added to the drop down via the database. Hence why 'None' would be returned and no others. It's like the memory is being wiped clean. :/

Comment: Hi @Jadeh, Could you remove pre inserted list item none (below one) and insert it at zero index after bind? As "None" is inserted at 0, it will be set default selected. I have modified the answer above.

Comment: Only problem is that is more or less the same as my first option, which also didn't work

Comment: Hi @Jon P, if this one haven't solved, it could be something with pageload as you said earlier. Probably, something to do with postback event.